# Excellent way of expanding tuple separated by underscore in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Given a tuple of two variable `('a','E1_g1')`, I would like to expand it into tuple of three variable `('a','E1', 'g1')`.

The following code should answer the objective

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 9))

_names = ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a']
_idx = ['E1_g1','E1_g2','E1_g3',
        'E2_g1','E2_g2','E2_g3',
        'E3_g1','E3_g2','E3_g3']
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([_names, _idx])

df= pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns=columns)

ntuple=[]
for dg in df.columns:
    A,B=dg
    f,r=B.split('_')
    ntuple.append((A,f,r))

# df.colums=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(ntuple) # WIP since I still got an error here
```

But, I wonder whether there is another way, that perhaps can be improve especially the step within the `for-loops`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're attempting? You seem to be trying to create a multi-index? Is `_idx` just for example, or are you getting these data from an existing dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for interest @ddejohn in this OP. Actually, the list of tuple is exisiting columns name. Ultimately, I would like to expand from two to three multiindex column.

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe.

Comment: Hi @ddejohn, I have edit the post to reflect my earlier comment to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the cleanest, but this is what I was able to do:

```py
idx = df.columns.to_flat_index()
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, idx.str.join("_").str.split("_")))
```

Output:

```py
MultiIndex([('a', 'E1', 'g1'),
            ('a', 'E1', 'g2'),
            ('a', 'E1', 'g3'),
            ('a', 'E2', 'g1'),
            ('a', 'E2', 'g2'),
            ('a', 'E2', 'g3'),
            ('a', 'E3', 'g1'),
            ('a', 'E3', 'g2'),
            ('a', 'E3', 'g3')],
           )
```

However, since the `dtype` is object, you really can't get much faster. In fact, a plain comprehension is a bit faster:

```py
n = len(df.columns)
lvl_0, lvl_1 = df.columns.levels

[(a, b, c) for a, (b, c) in zip(*lvl_0*n, lvl_1.str.split("_"))]
```

Performance:

```py
In [4]: %timeit pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(tuple, idx.str.join("_").str.split("_")))
914 µs ± 60.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(a, b, c) for a, (b, c) in zip(*lvl_0*n, lvl_1.str.split("_"))])
877 µs ± 53.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The only real benefit is the relative simplicity of the syntax in the first example.

Comment: Awesome, but, still better than the original implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
new_list = [tuple([_names[i]] + _idx[i].split("_")) for i in range(len(_idx))]
```

Output -

```
[('a', 'E1', 'g1'),
 ('a', 'E1', 'g2'),
 ('a', 'E1', 'g3'),
 ('a', 'E2', 'g1'),
 ('a', 'E2', 'g2'),
 ('a', 'E2', 'g3'),
 ('a', 'E3', 'g1'),
 ('a', 'E3', 'g2'),
 ('a', 'E3', 'g3')]
```